# Kind of received data via socket

Tags: sockets, delphi

Is there any way/trick/algorithm that allows me to know what kind of data is coming via socket? I can send both text and files via socket, but I wonder what I'm getting to treat differently.
Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way/trick/algorithm that allows me to know what kind of data is coming via socket?

No there is not, and it should be obvious that this is impossible. It's perfectly possible for a binary file and a text file to be identical at the binary level. In which case, how could you distinguish between them.

Sockets are simply a communication layer. It is up to you to determine the protocol for that communication.

Comment: Why so harsh? :) See my anwser.

Comment: It's incredible how we are blind until the answer falls into our laps.. thanks man

Comment: @LeandroHermesNeto, do not be so desperate. See my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a trick, exactly that. Unix command 'file' has a lot of heuristics built into it, which allows it to make a very educated guessess regarding random file contents. You can employ it by, for example, saving your data into a temporary file on disk and running file on it. Of course, it is non-binding, but file is good at what it does.

Comment: Thanks @SergeyA, but I don't think I could use it in Windows. Could I?

Comment: I'm sure it could be compiled for Windows, but it's just a heuristic. The right way to deal with this is to be precise about what you send. Define a clear protocol and follow it. Don't do what SergeyA is suggesting and try to allow arbitrary data to be transmitted.

Comment: @David, you are too harsh for no reason. Using heuristics is totally OK depending on conditions. For instance, FTP clients use heuristics to determine if the file has to be transferred in binary or text mode. It is a good thing to do.

Comment: @SergeyA And often the FTP clients get it wrong. I don't buy the idea that you should design a protocol by accepting arbitrary content and trying to guess what it is.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, apparently, the whole and wonderful branch of software development called fuzzy logic does not deserve your attention. Suit yourself.

Comment: @SergeyA Heuristics has its place. But when you control both ends of a communication channel, that's not it. Why you you prefer guessing over a protocol?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I have never seen an indication that OP controls both ends.

Comment: It's right there in the question. Both ends are controlled by the asker.

Comment: The file command is great until [you can't print on Tuesdays](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cupsys/+bug/255161). (Skim till comment 28.)

Comment: ' I can send both text and files via socket' - to me it sounds like the general statement of possibility, not that the author is really doing the sending.

Comment: @RobKennedy, that's is inseprable from the nature of heuristic (in general sense). Since heurtics are, basically, an attempt to emulate people with programms, we should expect heurstic programms to simply decline to perform, like a human can. Than we need to deprive misbehaving programs of resource (say, lower their memory allowance) until they start behaving out of neccessity, like humans do. There will be criminal programms, robbing others instead of working, and those we'd have to jail. Capital punishments for them (kill -9) would be hot topic. Oh, joy!

Comment: Hot discussion here ... I control both ends of the channel, and created a protocol. It was the simplest and accurate way to solve. Thank you all.